# ImportError: cannot import name 'Dispatcher' from 'pydispatch'

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, dispatcher

I have installed pydispatch using  - `pip install pydispatch` - in cmd

```
C:\Users\masysna1\Desktop\aswath-hiwi\cortex-v2-example-master\Demo>pip install pydispatch
Requirement already satisfied: pydispatch in c:\users\masysna1\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5.2 in c:\users\masysna1\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from pydispatch) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama>=0.2.7 in c:\users\masysna1\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from pydispatch) (0.4.4)
```

but when I run `from pydispatch import Dispatcher` in python. I get the following error

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Dispatcher' from 'pydispatch'
```

before this was working fine, can anyone help me

Comment: Are you sure you are working on same python environement where you installed your library?

Comment: Try adding `help("modules")` at the very top of your script and see if you can find pydispatch in the list of installed packages

Comment: I am able to import pydispatch but facing error while running,  from pydispatch import Dispatcher

Comment: after adding help("modules"), I am able to find pydispatch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pip install python-dispatch`.